# Removing empty nodes from XML using XSLT - Attributes should not be removed from non-empty nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using below template to remove empty nodes from an XML, but it is also removing the class attribute from the non-empty nodes:

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I don't want to remove attributes from the non-empty nodes. Please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```